# Adding dollar values from visible table column

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has a bunch of info, one of which is a column full of money values. It looks like the following.

```
$23.21
$347.34
$3,200,884.00
```

I can add up the values server-side, but using the filters, I don't want to hit the server again for the info. How do I add up the values so I can total it at the bottom of the table?

The tricky part is that based on a filter, I show or hide certain values so I only want to total the visible monetary values.

Comment: can you post the html in which those values are ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (*cant be precise without knowing the actual html*)

```
var total = 0;

// the selector must be adjusted to the actual html
$('td.price:visible').each(function(){
   var value = $(this).text().slice(1).replace(/,/g,'');
   total += +value;
});

// use the total variable here to display it somewhere in your page
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks a million!

Comment: Do you think you could explain that regex?

Comment: the `slice(1)` removes the `$` character from the start and the regex matches all `,` characters and removes them. the `g` sets the global flag so that it will match **all** commas in the string. So you end up with something like `3200884.00` which can be parsed to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo-element to insert your '$' sign via CSS. This way you can put a pure number inside your cells.

```js
var sum = 0;

var cells = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');
for(var i=0; i< cells.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(cells[i].innerText);
  }

document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].innerText = sum;
```

```css
td.dollar:before {
  content: "$";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sum dollar">12</td>
    <td class="sum dollar">28</td>
    <td class="total dollar"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```